# How to calculate the hot spare PSU power consumption

Tags: power-supply, power

All servers on my rack have hot spare PSU, the circuit is 20amps and 2400 watts max. lets say we load 80% of total watts which is 1920 watts. Do I have to calculate the hot spare as part of total power consumption? Does spare psu consume power when it is standing by?

Example. one of my server gets 2 x 750w PSU, so the total power consumption is 1500w on the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, looks like we don't need to calculate the spare PSU for total power consumption on each rack.

*Dual-corded equipment adds redundancy to IT hardware, and the lines share power load. If a dual-corded server has two 300-Watt power supplies, it can still draw no more than 300 Watts in your power design, because each power supply has to be able to handle the server's full load (not including power supply efficiency calculations).*

[How do I estimate server power consumption per rack?](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/answer/How-do-I-estimate-server-power-consumption-per-rack)